# How to install Django 1.5 using pip?

Tags: django, pip, django-1.5

How to install Django 1.5 ? `pip install django==1.5` not working.

Is Django1.5 a stable version?

Comment: Don't know why this was voted to be closed, it really shouldn't be.  Questions about `pip` and package versions seem pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: pip is a software tool commonly used by most django programmers - this is about as on topic as you can get for a question tagged django - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as at 19 feb 2013 the latest version is 1.4.3. See the [docs](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

If you do want 1.5 you can get it from github -

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.5b2#egg=django
```

UPDATE

The latest current version (1.5.1 as at 7th June 2013) can be installed with

```
pip install django
```